# extracting an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/TurtleWolf/pen/MoJeQy)

On line 19, the event listener calls an anonymous function, I'd like to break this out into its own function, but I also think I need to be passing a 3rd argument in. possibly the padz class, or maybe the audio tags.. maybe a combination of both, but not sure of the syntax to do that.

**JavaScript**

```
var clickCounter = 0;
var currentLevel = 0;
var simon_sSequence = [];
var player_sInput = [];
const audioTapper = document.querySelector("#audioT");
const audioError = document.querySelector("#audioE");
const levelDisplay = document.getElementById("level_Display");
const simonzSequence = document.getElementById("simon_sSequence");
const playerInput = document.getElementById("player_sInput");
const start_Tapper = document.querySelector(".startTapper");
const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".padz");
// Convert the padz list to an array that we can iterate over using .forEach()
Array.from(pads).forEach((pad, index) => {
  // Get the associated audio element nested in the padz-div
  const audio = pad.querySelector("audio");
  // Add a click listener to each pad which
  // will play the audio, push the index to
  // the user input array, and update the span
  pad.addEventListener("click", () => {
    player_sInput.push(index);
    if (player_sInput[clickCounter] !== simon_sSequence[clickCounter]) {
      audioError.play();
      $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 100);
      $("#container").effect( "shake", {times:100}, 1000, 'linear' );
      $("body").animate({ backgroundColor: "gray" }, 5000);
      //console.log("wrong");
    } else {  //end of if
      audio.play();
      playerInput.textContent = "Player's reply " + player_sInput;
      clickCounter++;
        //console.log(clickCounter);
    }   //end of else
  });   //end of EventListener
});     //end of Array.from(pads).forEach((pad, index)
start_Tapper.addEventListener("click", (resetStart)); //end of EventListener
function resetStart() {
  //generate a random number & push it to simon_sSequence
  simon_sSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
  simonzSequence.textContent = "Simon says " + simon_sSequence;
  playerInput.textContent = "Player's reply " + player_sInput;
  //for each in the array set time interval(300ms);
  //dipslay hover effect
  //play pad sound
  audioTapper.play();
  player_sInput = []; //clear player's input for this turn
  clickCounter = 0;
  currentLevel++;
  levelDisplay.textContent = "Level: " + currentLevel + " " + simon_sSequence.length + " " + player_sInput.length;
}
```

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXgvYE?editors=0010

Comment: maybe, can I call the function from outside of the constant or will it be effected by scope?

Comment: outside of the array, I mean. The constant is being set inside the array. But I'll need to be able to call the function when not inside the for each loop building the array of pads.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/calling-arguments-in-an-event-handler/267114